# Does Intersection Observer works from inside of a cross-domain iframe, with respect to the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, intersection-observer

Is there a way to determine from inside of a cross-domain iframe if the iframe is in view or not?
I was trying to achieve this using Intersection Observer API. But it seems to work only for same-domain iframe and not cross-domain. I checked the Intersection Observer API documentation(both on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/)), but couldn't find anything related to this. I hope I'm not missing anything here.

Here is the example code

Main Html Page

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin:700px auto;text-align:center;">
        <iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" height="250px" width="300px"
            id="aax_if_aax_sidebar-btf-1" allowtransparency="true" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/iframe.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Embedded Iframe Page

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iframe</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="abc" style="background-color: black;width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <script>
        setupIntersectionObserver = function (adContainer) {
            console.log('setting up observer', observer);
            var observer = new IntersectionObserver(
                function (entries) {
                    console.log('observer triggered', entries);
                },
                {
                    root: null,
                    rootMargin: '10px',
                    threshold: 0
                }
            );
            observer.observe(adContainer);

        };

        setupIntersectionObserver(document.getElementById('abc'))
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If I run the main page locally, then the intersection observer inside the iframe works only if the page is browsed using `127.0.0.1:8080`, and not for `localhost:8080` (cross-domain)

Does Intersection Observer works from inside of a cross-domain iframe, with respect to the viewport?

Answer (score 10):

I do not believe that there are any restrictions on cross-origin IntersectionObservers, however in my understanding they should have no explicit `root` set. In your case that would mean removing `root: null` from IntersectionObserver's configuration in the sub-frame.

It is important to note however, that your specified `rootMargin` value will not take effect in the cross-origin case [as per the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#dom-intersectionobserver-rootmargin) it is only applied "for targets which belong to the same unit of related similar-origin browsing contexts".

You might also need to explicitly switch your JavaScript context in dev tools to the sub-frame to see the log message. [Example in Chrome Dev Tools.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AToe.png)

This use case is supported by WebKit & Blink for sure, because they have automated testing specifically for cross-origin IntersectionObserver: [main frame page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/57644d439ce9bfee85efedff9f27a31e3e0bd3f5/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests/http/tests/intersection-observer/iframe-cross-origin.html), [sub-frame page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/57644d439ce9bfee85efedff9f27a31e3e0bd3f5/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests/http/tests/intersection-observer/resources/cross-origin-subframe.html)